# Indian rupee Not showing in Invoice PDF WooCommerce site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woothemes

Indian rupee Not showing in Invoice PDF WooCommerce site.Right to change fonts deja vu and other things but it didn't work. In Firefox symbols are not even showing on Chrome a square box is appearing next to the amount price I help would be appreciated,code treid

```
action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_google_fonts' );
function add_google_fonts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'google_web_fonts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dejavu/ttf/DejaVuSans.ttf' );
}
```

> Extended currency symbol support
>   Enable this if your currency symbol is not displaying properly
>   Enable font subsetting and Legacy mode 
>   has started showing currency symbol.....Resolved but only for chrome.problem remains on IE and firefox

[image: indian rupee image]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

As best I've been able to tell there the rupee symbol isn't a part of the DejaVu font. In this situation I would just use FontAwesome5: [Rupee Symbol](https://fontawesome.com/icons/rupee-sign?style=solid). Otherwise I would look into using a different webfont.

Comment: nope its there by default and not working.it works fine everywhere

Comment: In that case can you provide a screen shot or link so we can see the issue you're having?

Comment: Is PHP MB String installed on your server? (you can check this in the Status tab of the PDF Invoice settings)

Comment: Can you post a link to the sample PDF? The only thing I can think is the font is not being used and whatever is being used as a fallback doesn't support the rupee symbol.

Comment: using wampserver as of now....but yes its  working now...cleared cachw   :( ...thanks a lot for giving your time.... :)